# Share contact in iOS, sms or mms?

Tags: ios, sms, contacts, mms

Hi I am trying to share contact (vcard) through sms/mms gateway, should i encode contact and send as sms, or attach contact to mms?

What is the way of iPhone doing that. I cannot find any document clearly states that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default iOS gives possibility to share Contact through email or MMS, so You should probably use MMS or email.